# Added subview is showing after a delay

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, subview

I have function called loadMainView() which is called from viewDidLoad() as below

```
func loadMainView() {

        masterView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.bgScrollView!.contentSize.width,self.bgScrollView!.contentSize.height))
        masterView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        bgScrollView!.addSubview(masterView!)

        backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: self.masterView!.bounds)
        backgroundImage!.image = UIImage(named: self.backgroundImageName!)
        self.masterView!.addSubview(backgroundImage!)

        Common.sharedCommon.postRequestAndHadleResponse(kAllowedPaths.kPathGetAllNotes, body: nil) { (result, response) -> Void in

            if (result == true) {

                let respData = response.objectForKey("data")
                self.notesDataList = respData! as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
                self.showExisting()

            }
        }

    }
```

In the loadMainView() function, I am making an async HTTP call to fetch a data source and once the data source is loaded, I am calling another function called showExisting() whose body is as below

```
func showExistingNotes() {


        let xPoint = 100
        var yPoint = 100

        let printNote = notesDataList[0]
        let noteText = printNote["noteText"] as! String
        let noteTextFont = printNote["noteTextFont"] as! String
        let noteTextFontSize = printNote["noteTextFontSize"] as! CGFloat
        let noteType = printNote["noteType"] as! String


        let dim = 40.0
        let note = WallNote(frame: CGRectMake(xPoint,yPoint,dim,dim), noteType:noteType, noteText: noteText, noteFont:noteTextFont, noteFontSize:noteTextFontSize, noteFontColor:kDefaultFontColor)
        note.wallnoteDelegate = self
        //print("subview added")
        self.masterView!.addSubview(note)

    }
```

As you can see, all I am doing in this function is adding a subview called "note" to "masterView". The code is working fine but the subview "note" is shown in screen after 10 or 15 secs delay.

I tried to add a print statement print("subview added") to see whether it is taking some time to reach that statement but print statement is called as soon as the data source is filled in loadMainView() function and the added subview after print statement is shown after 10 or 15 secs after the print statement.

I am not able to understand why I am getting this delay in showing the subviews.

Thanks

Comment: Your completion handler is probably getting called on a background thread.  You need to make any UI updates on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is async task it is executed in background thread and all the ui updations has to happen in main thread. Thus you have to explicitly call ui updations in main thread. Try out following code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     if (result == true) {
        let respData = response.objectForKey("data")
        self.notesDataList = respData! as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
        self.showExisting()
    }
}
```